# remove a list of specific values from another list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am trying to remove a list of specific values from another list but I cannot find any resources to help me do so.

```
list1 <- list("a","b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g","h", "i", "j", "k")

list2 <- list("a","b","c","d")

list3 <- list1[-list2]
```

I would hope to get an output of the first list without a,b,c, or d. Instead I get

> Error in -list2 : invalid argument to unary operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` as the `list` elements have `length` 1

```
setdiff(list1, list2)
```

---

Or use `%in%` and negate (`!`)

```
list1[!list1 %in% list2]
```